# Given an interval stored as [{name, value},...], how would I find where x lies?

Tags: javascript, intervals

To easily illustrate this example, I have a interval like this:

```
        -6        -3        0         3        6                  
<-------o---------o---------o---------o--------o------->
  danger| warning |                   | normal | good
```

Which I store as an object, (notice nothing for interval -3 to 3)

EDIT: This is data structure is what I've been given, cannot make any changes.

```
{ name: 'good', value: 6 },
{ name: 'normal', value: 3 },
{ name: 'warning', value: -3 },
{ name: 'danger', value: -6 },
```

Given a value `x` I want to determine where it sits. So if:

- `x = 3 or 4`, it will return `normal`
- `x = 6 or 100`, it will return `good`
- `x = -1 or 1 or -2`, it will return '' (since nothing was assigned to those intervals)
- and similarly for negative numbers

My implementation in js was to loop through each object and if it was `>=`, it will overwrite. But I'd then write the same code again for negatives but with `<=`, does anyone have a better implementation?

```
var x = 4;
var returnInterval = '';
for (var point in interval) {
   if (x >= interval[point].value) {
       returnInterval = interval[point].name;
   }
}

return returnInterval;
```

Comment: Your data structure does *not* make it clear that -3 to 3 has no associated text.

Comment: The data structure I what I've been given to work with, we'll just need a work around.

Comment: If you can't change the structure then yes, I think you'll have to have two loops, perhaps with an if/else to decide which loop. Otherwise I don't think you can handle the -3 to 3 range having no associated text. Note though that such a solution assumes a hard-coded centre point.

Comment: Is your data structure an Array? It seems to be, but then you've used *for..in*.

Comment: It's an array of objects, code is just a quick example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider defining your ranges like this:

```
[
  { name: 'good', range: [6, Infinity },
  { name: 'normal', range: [3, 6] },
  { name: 'warning', value: [-6, -3] },
  { name: 'danger', value: [-Infinity, -6] }
]
```

With the existing data, you can build such a range like so:

```
var points = [
  { name: 'danger', value: -6 },
  { name: 'warning', value: -3 },
  { name: 'normal', value: 3 },
  { name: 'good', value: 6 }
];

// PRE CONDITION: elements are sorted by value (ascending)
var prev = -Infinity;

for (i = 0, j = 0; i <= points.length; ++i) {
  var current = i == points.length ? Infinity : points[i].value;

  if (prev >= 0 || current <= 0) {
    points[j].range = [prev, current];
    ++j;
  }

  prev = current;
}
```

It basically skips the segment with negative start and positive finish value.

Then, you can do simple bounds checks for each region.

```
function name(value)
{
  for (var i = 0; i != points.length; ++i) {
    var range = points[i].range;
    if (value >= range[0] && value <= range[1]) {
      return points[i].name;
    }
  }
  return '';
}
```

The nitty gritty of whether the checks are >=, >, < or <= is up to you.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I'm bound to the current api so I can't do much. I will update my post to include this fact.

Comment: @VeraWang I've included the code to convert your current values into ranges.

Comment: Thanks. Slightly relevant question: what's the best format to store infinity a database that's `parseInt` friendly in js?

Comment: @VeraWang You probably would have to make a compromise between INF and the largest number that can be represented by your database :)

Answer (score 1):

This fits your data structure, but it seems a bit brittle. It just applies different logic depending on which side of the centre the value is on. It can be applied to any size range data array, as long as it has an even number of members.

```
var rangeData = [
  { name: 'good', value: 6 },
  { name: 'normal', value: 3 },
  { name: 'warning', value: -3 },
  { name: 'danger', value: -6 }
];

function getRangeName(rangeData, value) {

  // Get the middle range index, assume length is always even
  var midRange = rangeData.length / 2 - 1;
  var v, next;

  for (var i=0, iLen=rangeData.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    v = rangeData[i].value;
    next = rangeData[i+1]? rangeData[i+1].value : -Infinity;

    // High side of middle
    if (i <= midRange && value >= v ) {
      return rangeData[i].name;

    // Low side of middle
    } else if (i > midRange && value <= v && value > next) {
      return rangeData[i].name;
    }
  }
  // Default if in middle
  return '';
}

var testData = [7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7];

testData.forEach(function(v) {
  console.log(v + ': ' + getRangeName(rangeData, v));
});
```

results:

```
7: good
6: good
5: normal
4: normal
3: normal
2:
1:
0:
-1:
-2:
-3: warning
-4: warning
-5: warning
-6: danger 
-7: danger
```